# how to reload video in axVLCPlugin21 using C#

Tags: c#, video-player

How to reload video in axVLCPlugin21 using C# my code just working one time and just open one video although open another video this my code:

```
private void panel2Open_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


      if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK)
      {
          axVLCPlugin21.playlist.add(openFileDialog1.FileName);
          axVLCPlugin21.playlist.play();
          axVLCPlugin21.playlist.items.clear();
      }

}
```

Comment: Is the axVLCPlugin21 disposable? do you have any error message?

Comment: really there is no message I don't know why any exception nothing 
when I open another video still showing first video no change

Comment: axVLCPlugin22.playlist.add(opf.FileName, opf.SafeFileName);
9.                axVLCPlugin22.playlist.play();
10.                if (IsPlaying == true)
11.                {
12.                    axVLCPlugin22.playlist.next();
13.                }

Comment: isPlaying! what is this ? this is bool or ?

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine for me even I used it by getting video links for Datagridview:

```
 string videoSource=dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Link"].Value.ToString();   
 axVLCPlugin21.playlist.add(videoSource, "video", " ");
 axVLCPlugin21.playlist.next();
 axVLCPlugin21.playlist.play();
```